# FileZilla new connection - nothing happens

Tags: ftp

I have updated my current FileZilla application -- and have as well cleared out all unnecessary connections that were saved, and now I have about 5 saved. This has never occurred before, **until my last 2 recent attempts at a 'new connection' -- I have multiple times, inserted the correct FTP credentials and FileZilla spins for approximately 1 second, and then outputs 'Not connected to any server'.** I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to go through if you manually type out the full password - a copy > paste resulted in my error.